# Lenovo Ideapad 320 touchpad drag and drop does not work on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, driver, touchpad

On my Lenovo Ideapad 320 touchpad drag and drop does not work. Touch click and scroll with fingers works.
Please help me troubleshoot
This is my configuration (please let me know if anything more is required )

Thankyou:-)

```
$ cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.2
DISTRIB_CODENAME=sonya
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 18.2 Sonya"
NAME="Linux Mint"
VERSION="18.2 (Sonya)"
ID=linuxmint
ID_LIKE=ubuntu
PRETTY_NAME="Linux Mint 18.2"
VERSION_ID="18.2"
HOME_URL="http://www.linuxmint.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://forums.linuxmint.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/"
VERSION_CODENAME=sonya
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial

$ uname -a
Linux darling 4.8.0-53-generic #56~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue May 16 01:18:56 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 1921 (rev 0a)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 Plus Bluetooth (rev 99)
```

Comment: Distro doesn't make much sense, until you checked on vanilla and, perhaps, linux-next versions of kernel.

Comment: Same problem, except with Ubuntu 22.04 on Ideapad Flex 5. Any hints on what could fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with my touchpad. If you have synclient, try

```
synclient ClickPad=1
```

And see if that helps at all.

Comment: I tried this in Linux Mint Cinnamon but did not work. BUT On Linux Mint Mate it worked. :-) In which file should I put this configuration to make it permanent? Thanks!

Comment: Yes it helped.To make configuration permanent ( i.e survive a reboot ) I  added I added           Option "Clickpad" "1"        to the first section in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/60-synaptics-options.conf 
 file

Comment: That's great to hear; I'm glad it worked! I actually put it in a script called fix-clickpad.sh that I run on each reboot. Your way sounds better.

Comment: I first tried to put a cron entry in root like " @reboot synclient Clickpad=1 " but it didn't help so tried the other one